# Ionic - Touch events not firing in IE

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an Angular/Ionic web page. With a  the touch events do not fire in IE - they DO in FF and other browsers. Any idea why the touch events don't work

See
http://play.ionic.io/app/89b1034912dd

try in IE on then on FF on a tablet.

Is it because of the focus firing first?

Answer (score 1):

Here I want you to emphasize on some things.

1. IONIC doesn't go well with Windows Phone, or IE in your case. Accept it for sometime now. Those guys getting salaries for IONIC would be working on it.
2. Coming to your application, I see touch event working as expected, but the difference is, in IE dropdown width is limited (if you'd tap on "Default"/ "Red", it'll work), where as in other browsers, even if you touch beside the text, it is working(ideal situation).
3. Don't worry about this issue now, your app will run just perfect on IOS/Android, with some minor difficulties with WP.

Comment: gotta be some way to improve it?  I need target wp first

Comment: Well, if it is WP first, I believe You'd need to need to do a lot of customization. What I'd suggest, spare sufficient time for testing and in case of discrepency, have a work around by having very specific css to perticular div/id. Sometime back, when I was making a WP app, there was  a case where ng-click was getting called twice, which very recently got fixed I guess. So, they are doing progress in this as well bit by bit.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by moving the `ngCordova` dependency to the top of the dependencies array.

So my module declaration is:

```
angular.module('AppName', [
    ngCordova,
    ngCordovaBluetoothle,
    ngRoute,
    mobile-angular-ui,
    AppName.controllers.Home,
])
```

Answer (score 0):

-> With scroll="false", gestures doesn't work unless you apply my patch
-> Without scroll="false", gestures work perfectly, but if you apply my patch then scroll doesn't work.

So the best solution by now is to keep the scroll in the content-view